# Grails date binding

Tags: data-binding, grails, date

In Grails, one can 'bindData' in controller:

```
Book b = new Book()
bindData(b, params)
```

What if I have a date field with specific format (e.g. yyyy-MM-dd) from user input? In Spring, we can use registerCustomEditor(). How about Grails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Grails 1.1.1, you can implement a PropertyEditorRegistrar and use that to specify a  format. See http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-1-1-1-change-in-binding-date-properties-td1323105.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you already come across the [Extended Data Binding Plugin](http://www.grails.org/Extended+Data+Binding+Plugin)?

From the documentation on the site, it appears to offer both aspects which you are referring to

- Allow customization of the DataBinder that will be used to parse user-defined input and populate objects (typically domain objects) with custom PropertyEditors on both application-wide and controller-specific levels.as String.
- Extend controllers with dynamic methods to allow data binding and bean wrapping.

Comment: Yes, I've already come across that. But I think it's a bit clumsy as you have to remember to do bind and wrapbean all the time. So I ask if anyone know a simpler method